# Rotating Disk and Conservation of Energy AP Physics Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

> A uniform solid disk of radius 3.6 m and mass
> 17.7 kg is free to rotate on a frictionless pivot
> through a point on its rim.
> If the disk is released from rest in the
> position shown by the solid circle, what is
> the speed of its center of mass when the
> disk reaches the position indicated by the
> dashed circle? The acceleration of gravity
> is 9.8 m/s2. Answer in units of m/s.
>
> [image]

I got the answer right by doing Ug = Krot. mgh = 1/2*m*(v/r)^2 with I = 1/2*m*r^2 + md.(pivot) However, why is translational kinetic energy not accounted for? The center of mass is moving. I also got the same answer by doing Ug = Krot + Ktrans, but the moment of inertia I used was just 1/2*mr^2 (center of mass).

Comment: These two methods (finding the moment of inertia about a fixed point vs. adding the translational & rotational kinetic energy of the CM) will generally give you the same answer; they're two ways of quantifying the same thing.

Comment: Why is translational kinetic energy not factored in when you use the fixed point as the moment of inertia? Isn't it still technically moving since translational is based on the center of mass?